# Можно ли из 3-х массивов,и из 3-х циклов foreach, в каждом я картинки из массивов добавляю в listBox, сделать одни массив с одним циклом?

Tags: c#

```
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(aPath);

FileInfo[] fi = di.GetFiles("01.jpg");
FileInfo[] fd = di.GetFiles("02.jpg");
FileInfo[] fk = di.GetFiles("03.jpg");

foreach(FileInfo fc in fi)
{
  listBox1.Items.Add(fc.Name);
}
foreach(FileInfo fc in fd)
{
  listBox1.Items.Add(fc.Name);
}
foreach(FileInfo fc in fk)
{
  listBox1.Items.Add(fc.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вопрос об упрощении и сокращении кода, то можно так.

```csharp
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(aPath);
string[] fileNames = new string[] { "01.jpg", "02.jpg", "03.jpg" };

foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
{
    FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles(fileName);
    foreach(FileInfo fi in files)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(fi.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо , то что нужно

Comment: @АлексейХодырев не забудьте отметить ответ как принятый.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i = 0; i < fi.Count() + fd.Count() + fk.Count(); i++) {
  if (i < fi.Count()) { 
     listBox1.Items.Add(fi[i].Name); 
     continue;
  }
  if (i < fi.Count() + fd.Count()) { 
     listBox1.Items.Add(fd[i-fi.Count()].Name); 
     continue;
  }
  if (i < fi.Count() + fd.Count() + fk.Count()) { 
     listBox1.Items.Add(fk[i-fi.Count() - fd.Count()].Name); 
     continue;
  }
}
```